# Error mapping entities

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Am following the example given in the book `Programming Google App Engine` to create a `OneToMany` relationship between two entities `Book and BookReview`.In the book it was done like this:

```
@Entity(name="Book")
public class Book {
....

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BookReview> bookReviews;
}
```

and then a back-reference is made to the book class like this:

```
@Entity(name="BookReview")
public class BookReview {
...
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="bookReviews")
private Book book;
}
```

But when i try this

```
@Entity 
 public class Store {

@Id
String storeName;

@OneToMany
private List<Employee> employees;

}
////////////
@Entity
public class Employee {


@Id
int employeeId;

@ManyToOne(mappedBy="employees")
private Store store;
```

}

`@ManyToOne(mappedBy="employees")` is marked with an error saying `"The attribute mappedBy is undefined for the annotation type ManyToOne"`.And it suggests i use one of `cascade,fetch,optional,targetEntity` instead.Am really confused here.Am using Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Any decent JPA docs would tell you that a 1-N bidir relation needs *mappedBy* on the side with the collection. The error message is pretty clear too

Comment: Your answer isn't very helpful.Just like the comment you made in my [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009499/modeling-relationships-jpa-between-entities-in-google-app-engine-datastore) question.If i knew the cause of the "pretty clear" error i wouldn't be asking this question.Besides,am wondering why the example works in the book and gives an error in my code.

Comment: Which bit of the "mappedBy should be at the side with the Collection" is troubling to you? Store has a Collection field, and there is no "mappedBy" (yet I tell you that this is where you should put it, as would any decent JPA docs), and Employee has "mappedBy" but that is illegal (as the message tells you). This book, if it really says what you put, has a serious typo (and Eclipse showing up the fact that this attribute doesnt exist in ManyToOne ought to be enough to conclude the same)